# What is the name of this lady beside Snape?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification

[image]

At first I thought it was McGonagall, but I didn't really recognize this woman in the left corner. What is her name and role in the movie?

Comment: I have no problem with this question but I think it will transpire more such identify this person from screenshot questions in coming days. I don't know whether that is good or bad

Comment: Which film is this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That, is [Madam Irma Pince](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Irma_Pince) (*or generally addressed in the books as Madam Pince*). She is the librarian at Hogwarts.

Her description, collected across the HP books:

> ***One of Madam Pince's most striking physical attributes was looking like an underfed vulture. She was also very thin and irritable-looking.*** 
>  <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets: Chapter 10 (The Rogue Bludger)*</sub>

---

According to [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1090693/), **Sally Mortemore** is mentioned to be playing the role of Madam Pince. Per her IMDB page,

[image]

Additionally, from the film, below is a screenshot of the end credits supporting IMDB's claim.

So, the person in question is undoubtedly Madam Irma Pince (played by Sally Mortemore).

[image]

Comment: I'm not questioning your ID but how do you know it's her? Was she called by name in the movie or are you ID'ing her by description? Just curious...

Comment: @JeffC I saw it on numerous sources including HKWikia, Pinterest, Wikipedia and also on IMDb. Even a simple google search on Madam Pince gives you that exact photo. I don't think all sources could be wrong; and I concluded thusly.

Comment: The actress credited for the role of Madame Pince in CoS on IMDB looks enough like the character in the screenshot for me : https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1090693/. I think the only more you could do is check the actual credits of the film to make sure IMDB has the right actress

Comment: @Etheur that is actually useful. I found her in the end credits. The new answer is ready :)

Comment: @shree we would think all sources couldn't be wrong, but there's this: https://xkcd.com/978/

Comment: A photo of Sally Mortemore for comparison/confirmation would improve this answer.

Comment: Many photos of Sally Mortemore, as suggested by @KRyan for comparison/confirmation, readily available by Google search: [Sally Mortemore](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Sally+Mortemore&rlz=1C1GCEA_enAU782AU782&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBvpC8wKTbAhUDWrwKHWhLCwMQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=974)

Comment: Which movie and which part of the story is that scene from? Did the librarian have dinner with the teachers at their table in the book? If I remember even Hagrid had dinner with the teachers only after he became one himself( or am I mistaken?)

Comment: @user13267 a movie isn't an exact clone of a book so I don't quite remember Madam Irma Prince having a dinner with the teachers. Professors eat their dinner meals at the teachers' table. But the credits at the end of "Chamber of Secrets" film verified Sally Mortermore played Madam Prince's role. Google isn't very reliable but her pictures all around the internet is identical enough to this lady in the image above. That character depicts a teacher.